# What is global address space?

Tags: caching, computer-science

I was reading about Cache-only memory access on Wikipedia. There is a line saying that "In NUMA, each address in the global address space is typically assigned a fixed home node". I don't know what is global address space. Can someone tell me what is global address space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a machine with multiple nodes, each node has a set of addressable memory locations--its local address space.  The global address space of the machine is the union of these sets.